# Getting schema information within a biztalk pipeline component

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Good morning,
I'm interested in writing a pipeline component that's aware of the document schema it's decoding. I see there's a function to get to schema information within the component:

```
IDocumentSpec spec = pContext.GetDocumentSpecByType("name-of-your-schema");
```

Can you access the document schema name that's assigned in the pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

You can get it from the message's context like so:

```
private static readonly PropertyBase SchemaStrongNameProperty = new BTS.SchemaStrongName();
private static readonly PropertyBase MessageTypeProperty = new BTS.MessageType();

public IBaseMessage Execute(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg)
{
    // Get by schema strong name (.NET type)
    string schemaStrongName = pInMsg.Context.Read(SchemaStrongNameProperty.Name.Name, SchemaStrongNameProperty.Name.Namespace) as string;
    pContext.GetDocumentSpecByName(schemaStrongName);

    // Get by message type (XML NS#Root Node)
    string messageType = pInMsg.Context.Read(MessageTypeProperty.Name.Name, MessageTypeProperty.Name.Namespace) as string;
    pContext.GetDocumentSpecByType(messageType);

    // Rest of your pipeline component's code...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the method pInMsg.Context.Read() returns null. At run time SchemaStrongNameProperty.Name.Name = "SchemaStrongName". The namespace is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties". The schema strong name isn't in the message context.

Comment: In which stage will your component be running?

Comment: I was planning on using it in the disassemble stage. Perhaps I need to rewrite it to work in the validate stage? I'm actually trying to do cleanup of the data using information from the schema. Doing it post dis-assembly would work just as well.

Comment: I think the validate stage would be best. The disassembler sets that information, so you'll have to do it after that.